# How to view a website and can login using WebView in android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, webview

I put this code in my program for my app in android.

```
public class StudentModule extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_student_module);

    WebView ourBrow = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvStudent);
    ourBrow.loadUrl("http://sample.com/");
```

The problem is this... I can't log-in to that website even my `password` and `username` is correct.. :( please help me.

Comment: Your Question is too ambiguous can you please provide more details, cause the problem might be in website itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the website uses JavaScript, try enabling it before loading the url:
ourBrow.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);